# flexslider keeps crashing when i try to change settings

Tags: javascript

I have used all the latest [Flex Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) modules and library, I have created a View, with format of slideshow, the Slideshow Type is defaulting to Flexslider, and I'm using the default Optionset.

I have the title of the slide and the image being displayed. everything works as expected in terms of it being responsive, however, if I edit the View, then click Settings under Format, and then either click Save or Cancel, I get a few pages of rubbish displayed (see below) can anyone help?

> [{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"/rltc/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven","theme_token":"l_FB7jWDCmNamBi4J7kqnOrggLfAI3b3oWvjYgjabko"},"states":{"#edit-style-options-flexslider-views-slideshow":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[slideshow_type]\u0022]":{"value":"flexslider_views_slideshow"}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-timeout":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][transition_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-speed":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][transition_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-delay":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][transition_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-sync":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][transition_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-random":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][transition_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-start-paused":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][action_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-remember-slide":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][action_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-remember-slide-days":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][action_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true},":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][remember_slide]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-pause-in-middle":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][transition_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-pause-when-hidden":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][action_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-pause-when-hidden-type":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][action_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true},":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][pause_when_hidden]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-nowrap":{"visible":{":input[name=\u0022style_options[views_slideshow_cycle][action_advanced]\u0022]":{"checked":true}}},"#edit-style-options-views-slideshow-cycle-fixed-height":{"vis

Comment: i have managed to resolve this, i managed to find it on google here : https://drupal.org/node/1869988 . basically if you go into your jquery_update module, click configure, then change it from 1.8 to 1.7 it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this, I managed to find it on google here : [JQuery Update breaks Views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/1869988)  .

Basically if you go into your [jquery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module, click configure, then change it from 1.8 to 1.7 it works